# Javascript code exhibiting unexpected logical behaviour

Tags: javascript, html

My program is responding exhibiting unexpected behaviour.

**Expected behaviour of selectQuestion():**

Select a category of question at random and check the difficulty level required. 
Search through the list of questions, adding any meeting the criteria which have not recently been played to a list of potentialQuestions. If there are no questions meeting this randomly chosen criteria, then repeat the above step until questions are found.

**Actual behaviour of selectQuestion():**

`selectQuestion()` will select questions which are in `recentQuestions[]`, rather than selecting a new category at random.

**Additional Information:**

`dda[]` is an array of objects, each with a `category` and a `difficulty`.

`question[]` is an array of objects, each with a `question`, `answers[]`, `correctAnswer`, `category` and `difficulty`.

`recentQuestions[]` is an array of integers. (Each integer is the index of a question in `question[]`)

```
function selectQuestion()
{
    //Create an array we can use to store the numbers of any questions which meet our criteria
    var potentialQuestions = new Array();
    // While there are no questions which meet our criteria, pick new critieria
    // (This prevents the program from getting 'stuck' if criteria can't be met)
    while(potentialQuestions.length == 0) {
        // Select a category at random, retrieve the difficulty we're looking for
        var randomSelection = Math.floor(Math.random()*dda.length);
        var category = dda[randomSelection].category; 
        var difficulty = Math.floor(dda[randomSelection].difficulty+0.5);
        // For each question we have (in question[]) 
        for(q = 0; q < question.length; q++) {
                    // If the category and the difficulty meet our criteria
            if(question[q].category == category & question[q].difficulty == difficulty) {
                            // Check if the question has been played recently
                            // by looping through recentQuestions[] 
                var playedRecently = false; 
                for(r = recentQuestions.length; r=0; r++) {
                    if(recentQuestions[r] == q) {
                        playedRecently = true; 
                    }
                }
                // If the question has not been played recently 
                if(!playedRecently) {
                                    // Add it to potentialQuestions[]
                    potentialQuestions.push(q); 
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Select a question at random from our potential questions 
    var selectedQuestion = potentialQuestions[Math.floor(Math.random()*potentialQuestions.length)]; 

    // If 5 recent questions have been stored, remove the oldest 
    if (recentQuestions.length == 5) {
        recentQuestions.shift(); 
    }

    // Add the selected level to recentQuestions[]
    recentQuestions.push(selectedQuestion); 
    return selectedQuestion; 
}
```

I'm not sure where this behaviour is coming from. Any thoughts would be most welcome! Thanks!

**Solved!**

`for (r= recentQuestions.length; r=0; r++)` should have in fact been `for (r=0; r<recentQuestions; r++)` - definitely one of those days! Gah! Thanks all :)

Comment: for(r = recentQuestions.length; r=0; r++)   r=0 as loop condition is a mistake. And you can use r=recentQuestions.indexOf(q);

Comment: Tip: you should always `var` your local variables, even in `for` loops (otherwise `r` is global). For example: `for (var r=0; recentQuestions; r++)`

Comment: Despite participating in this question, I now feel it should be closed because it is too localized. There is some discussion on meta here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125384/debug-this-code-for-me-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second answer is like unto the first. You have an assignment in your for-loop condition rather than a comparison. (`=` instead of `==`).

It also looks like you intend to be counting down? So, should your increment be `r--` ?

Comment: Ah geez! No idea what pits of despair in my brain that code came from ;) 

It should have been `for(r = 0; r<recentQuestions.length; r++)` - it must be one of those days! 

Fixed :) Thank you for your help!

Comment: Glad I could spot the problem; but I hope you put the pain you experienced to good use... Don't forget to mark this as the answer with the check mark, if it is in fact so.

Comment: Indeed - I tried to but it was less than ten minutes at the time :) Thanks

Comment: Although I was helpful, I'm actually not sure whether this question belongs on SO, now that I research it. I was just reading this thread on meta, and it implies not: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123253/suggest-move-to-code-review

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement you have a single `&`; you probably want a `&&`.  `&` is a bitwise and,  not a logical and.

Comment: But note that `true & true==1`, `true & false==0`, and `false&false==0`, so the logic is upheld even if the OP is accidentally performing bitwise and instead of boolean. A good tip and good guess, but I don't believe this is the problem.

Comment: Thanks - had missed that! However, error still remains.